# Calculate Total Memory usage of single instance of a class in c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have a complex class with a lot of vectors of other classes and pointers. How can I calculate how much memory usage this class consumes after it instantiates including all its inside memory allocation?
I'm in c++, Qt, and win10.

```
class foo: public fooparent
{
public:
    foo();

    std::vector<foo2 *>  layers;
    foo3 *worker;
    std::string meta_data;
    int model_loaded;
};
```

Solution 1: One solution is to measure total app memory consumption before and after instantiate but is there any better way?

Comment: Ask your friendly memory manager, which will have byte-correct measurements.

Comment: If you mean `sizeof(foo) + layers.size()*sizeof(foo2)` etc ... then there is no workaround except just adding up all dynamically allocated memory that you are aware of. However, it will still not indicate how much memory your program might consume, because it's up to the operating system how much virtual memory it will decide to map to your process. It can be (and usually is) greater than the minimum required. Another way might be to run it under profiler e.g. valgrind - it will show you many bytes your process allocated (including c++ standard runtime stuff).

Comment: it depends what exactly you mean with "memory consumption of `foo`" and why you need to know. I suppose you do not mean `sizeof(foo)`, though many times thats just sufficient information. For pointer members its not that simple, because you need to say who owns the obejct they point to. Eg `layers` could have 1000000 elements but they can all point to the same instance, and that instance might be allocated and owned by someone else

Comment: @Botje, can you elaborate? I need only a single class, not the whole application

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai tnx for comment. Yes I mean all memory allocation that was done in that class, I don't need any allocation that happened in other places, let's make it more clear, I need to know how much memory was allocated during class construction including all other classes that instantiate inside foo like foo3

Comment: but you didnt show what memory allocation is done in that class. Only you know what is allocated by `foo` and what you want to add up. That or you measure it as Botje suggested. Write a program that allocates 10/100/1000 instances and see what your system memory manages says about memory consumption.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai That may work thanks, it's trivia to post the code as it should be treated as a black box as it instantiates a lot of classes that consist 100k lines of codes, it's impractical to dig in code

Comment: As 463035818_is_not_an_ai has commented, for the very least, we need to know whether those pointers are owning or not. If they are indeed non-owning, as raw pointer members in C++ usually should be, then the allocation is something like `sizeof(foo)+layers.capacity()*sizeof(foo2*)+meta_data.capacity()`, is this what you are looking for? However, this interpretation contradicts with your comment that you do care about foo3.

Comment: sizeof is not a solution, it just counts static allocated memory, I care about dynamic memory too

Comment: `layers.capacity()*sizeof(foo2*)` is the dynamic memory you need to store those pointers. If you are talking about the memories of the `foo2` objects themselves, then your pointers are owning, and your question is missing essential details.

Comment: "should be treated as black box" then you can only measure. As I said, when you have 1.000.000 raw pointers you cannot know whether they are owning and whether they point to 1 or to 100 different instances that were dynamically allocated.

Comment: @Pazel1374 Your memory allocator knows exactly when `new` or `malloc` is called and for how many bytes. You can take a snapshot before and after a call to `new foo` and see exactly what was allocated. For example, [Jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html) has a `stats.allocated` counter.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no better way than to measure.

Lets simplify the example:

```
struct foo_simple {
    std::vector<foo_simple*>  layers;
};
```

What is the memory consumption of one instance? Typically you care about `sizeof(foo_simple)` which is size of members plus padding. If you care about total memory consumed by members and also by instances where the members point you are out of luck. `foo_simple` might be used like this:

```
 foo_simple fs;
 for (int i=0;i < 100000; ++i) fs.push_back(new foo_simple);
```

In this case the pointers are owning pointers (and shouldnt be raw pointers in the first place, but thats beyond the scope of this question), and the memory "consumed" by `fs` is roughly `(100000 + 1) * sizeof(foo_simple)`.

Now consider this different usage:

```
 foo_simple a;
 foo_simple b;
 for (int i=0;i < 100000; ++i) a.push_back(&b);
```

Now `a` holds a vector with 100000 pointers but in total there are only 2 instances. Creating another `a` does not necessarily create another `b`.

---

You cannot know how much memory is consumed by an instance of a class in total. Especially when raw pointers are involved and you want to treat the rest of the code as "black box" then (unfortunately) you cannot know if those pointers are owning or not, whether the memory footprint of the pointees should be added or not. Note that also `std::shared_ptr` is not sufficient to bring clarity, because two `std::shared_ptr` can share the same instance. Only with `std::unique_ptr` you can be sure of the memory footprint, though also there you need to consider whether the `std::unique_ptr` is actually used to own a resource or not.

---

TL;DR: You can measure it by writing a small program that allocates 10/100/1000/100000 instances and use your systems memory manager to get an estimate of the memory consumption of a single instance. Given your constraints (code you didnt show is "black box") this is the best way.